# turtles finding partners in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am creating a code where turtles need to find partners. This is the procedure:

```
patches-own [occupied?]
turtles-own [partner fed?]

to find-partners
 let singles turtles with [partner = nobody]
 if not any? singles [ stop ]

  ask singles  
  [ lt random 50 
    rt random 50
    fd 1 ]

 ask turtles 
 [
  if (partner = nobody) and (any? other turtles in-radius 1 with [partner = nobody])
  [ set partner one-of other turtles in-radius 1 with [partner = nobody] 

    ask partner [ 
    set partner myself

]]]

end
```

I want this procedure to take place in 1 tick, but it takes ~500. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say exactly without your setup, but it seems like `while` is what you want. Try replacing `if not any? singles [stop]` with `while any? singles [`

The idea is that while there are any singles around, keep running this loop. Be careful, because if the "while" condition is never satisfied, the model will be stuck in the `while` loop. Therefore, you also need to include the line `set singles turtles with [ partner =  nobody ]` within the while loop. So all together, something like

```
to find-partners
     let singles turtles with [partner = nobody]
     while [ any? singles ] [
      ask singles  
      [ lt random 50 
        rt random 50
        fd 1 ]

     ask turtles 
     [
      if (partner = nobody) and (any? other turtles in-radius 1 with [partner = nobody])
      [ set partner one-of other turtles in-radius 1 with [partner = nobody] 

        ask partner [ 
        set partner myself

    ]]]

    set singles turtles with [partner = nobody]

    ]

end
```